# remove anchor not working

Tags: javascript, html4

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function removeLink(i)
{
    document.getElementById("tab2").deleteRow(i);
}
</script>


</head>
<body>
<form action="forth.php" method="post">
<table width="600" border="1" id="tab2">


<?php

    foreach($_POST as $key => $post2)
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <?php
    echo $post2.'<br />';
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $key;?>" value="<?php echo $post2;?>" />

    </td>
    <td><a href="#" onClick="removeLink(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex);">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php

    }

    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Next" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  </table>

</form>
</body>
```

guys you can see my anchor tag having onclick function of removeLink() but it does not delete the entire tr as expected. when im clicking the anchor generated link it does not perform any action. is there any issue like anchor not supporting inner objects define in removeLink(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex) ? guys help how it can be done

Comment: check for the javascript error in Firebug or any other error tracking tool. and let us know.

Comment: @MaulikVora there is no point of using firebug, its not showing anything no error. its just that when user clicks on remove link it does not delete that row however i have also defined my function

Comment: What browser are you using? This code works with Chrome.

Comment: try moving the JS call in href attribute rather than onclick..

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery. Include `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

And try this

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.deleteMe').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        //or u can hide that like $(this).parent().parent().hide.();
    })
});

</script>


</head>
<body>
<form action="forth.php" method="post">
<table width="600" border="1" id="tab2">


<?php

    foreach($_POST as $key => $post2)
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <?php
    echo $post2.'<br />';
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $key;?>" value="<?php echo $post2;?>" />

    </td>
    <td><a href="#" class="deleteMe">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php

    }

    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Next" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  </table>

</form>
</body>
```

Comment: He need to use normal javascript only

Comment: @bibin yes maulik is right i only have to use normal javascript to do this task, i have coded but can not debug where i went wrong that its not working

Answer (score 0):

first of change below code in your anchor onclick line.

```
onClick="removeLink(this);">
```

then try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function removeLink(obj){
var par=obj.parentNode;
while(par.nodeName.toLowerCase()!='tr'){
par=par.parentNode;
}
i = par.rowIndex;
document.getElementById("tab2").deleteRow(i);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @maulik for the help your life savior